# Sql query to find column matches across tables

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have 3 tables. Within those 3 tables are the same column names: part name, supplier, part id

The issue is that multiple suppliers may have the same part ID and trying to query and show if a part ID or part name is associated with multiple suppliers?

Comment: [sql-server] (aka MS SQL) and [mysql-workbench] (client software for MySQL) are not compatible. Adjust tags list.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Please take your time to read [ask] and possibly read through the starting topics in the help centre. Your question currently lacks enough detail to attract an adequate answer. Please click on [edit] and add more details to your question. Including examples of what you have tried, test data and table definitions will help attract answers. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can qualify your tables/columns in your query to separate. It's difficult to imagine what you are trying to do without seeing a sample of the data.

You could also prefix/pipe in descriptive text in your id columns to help separate the ids.

```
`Select 'supplier1-' || id, 'supplier2-' || id2
 From Table;
```